# How can I get a tooltip to work in this scenario using qtip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, qtip2

I have a table of venues, venuetypes and mapicons the relationship is:

- venue belong to venuetype
- venuetype belongs to mapicon

Each venue result is displayed on the index page as a partial with each partial containing the  venues associated map icon as a div which is positioned with a bit of javascript.

How can I add a tooltip to the mapicons which will display its associated venues name?

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Exunr/1/). *(I have added the qTip plugin as a resource)*

When you hover over the red circle I would like it to display a tooltip saying the venues name, Red Test and Blue test when hovering the blue circle.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the associated venue name I needed to assign an option for qTip to latch onto, I used title and added it to each map icon as its created in the partial:

```
<%= image_tag (venue.mapicon.url(:mapicon)), :title => venue.name %>
```

The rendered HTML then looks like this:

```
<img alt="Bluecircle" src="http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z397/lemmon8/redcircle.png" title="Blue Test" />
```

And qTip is implemented with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img[title]').qtip();
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Exunr/10/)

Answer (score 1):

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eVCtr/1/)

Some of your CSS styles need to be modified to make it look the way you want it to, but the tooltips now appear like you wanted them to.

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#venue_map_icon_11").hover(function() {
        $("#Tipvenue_map_icon_11").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#Tipvenue_map_icon_11").hide();
    });


    $("#venue_map_icon_9").hover(function() {
        $("#Tipvenue_map_icon_9").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#Tipvenue_map_icon_9").hide();
    });

});
```

## Modified HTML

```
<a href="/venues/9-red-test">
    <div class="venue_partial">
        <div id="Tipvenue_map_icon_9" class="venue_partial_name red" style="display:none;">Red Test</div>

        <div style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:100px;" class="mapicon">
            <img id="venue_map_icon_9" alt="Bluecircle" src="http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z397/lemmon8/redcircle.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="/venues/11-blue-test">
  <div class="venue_partial">
    <div id="Tipvenue_map_icon_11" class="venue_partial_name blue" style="display:none;">Blue Test</div>

    <div style="position:absolute;left:125px;top:75px;" class="mapicon"> 
        <img id="venue_map_icon_11" alt="Redcircle" src="http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z397/lemmon8/bluecircle.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: +1 for effort, I think I should have worded my question a bit better. Thanks for looking and the answer its just not exactly what I was after